# Hook into the "OnChange" event when user changes the "To" field when sending new email or replying an email in outlook

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to find a solution for hooking into the "OnChange" event of the "To" field in the "New" or "Reply" email window.

I know there might be no "OnChange" event on the "To" field, I just want to describe what I need.

My client may send hundreds of emails everyday, but if they send email to a specific address, I would like to provide a template for the wording, so the best practice will be:

Check the "To" field in real time, if it matches a specific address, update the body text to reflect the template wording.

Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn is being used.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So what are you having problem with? Setting up an event handler? Retrieving the right MailItem object to hook up the events? Or processing the data in the event handler?

Comment: Setting up an event handler, which could check the text content in the "To" field once it is changed when composing new email.

Comment: What is your exiting code?

Comment: I don't have exiting code for now, but I think the key line will be:
`myOutlookMail.Body = strTemplateBody;`
I just want to know how to setting up an event handler for the To field.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this sort of requirement.
As there is no OnChange event for To field, So I did it on Send button click.

Once the user clicks on the Send button,  apply the required template for the body text. Please write the below lines, so that the updated body text will be delivered to the recipients.

```
 Outlook.MeetingItem ItemSendObject = item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
 ItemSendObject.Body = appointmentItem.Body;
 item = ItemSendObject;
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution won't works for me, because I just need to provide a template before users start to writing the email, so that they will know what info should they provide.